# Extend abstract singleton class

Tags: php, singleton, abstract-class

If you had a factory class that creates new objects of some kind, and that factroy class is a singleton, like this:

```
class Database_Factory extends Base_Factory {
    private static $factory;
    private $objects = array();

    public function __get($profile) {
        // check for object and return it if it's created before
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (!self::$factory)
            self::$factory = new self();
        return self::$factory;
    }
}
```

The same code repeats anytime where some object needs it's own factory. So i decided to make this factory class abstract and implement only specific routines for each factory. But PHP does not allow to instantiate abstract class.

```
abstract class Base_Factory {
    public static function getInstance(){
        if (!self::$factory)
            self::$factory = new self();
        return self::$factory;
    }
}
```

Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Base_Factory

What would you do?

Comment: The question essentially is: how do i free myself from writing those getInstance (and maybe later some more) functions in every factory?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In PHP methods, `self` always refers to the class where the method is defined. Since version 5.3.0, PHP supports “late static binding”, where you can use the `static` keyword to access overridden static methods, as well as the function `get_called_class()` to get the name of the derived class in static context.

However, your design has a major flaw: The static property `$factory` defined in `Base_Factory` is shared across all derived classes. Therefore, the first time a singleton is created and stored in this property, all other calls to `getInstance()` will return the same object, no matter what derived class is used.

You could use a static dictionary mapping class names to singleton objects:

```
abstract class Base_Factory {
    private static $_instances = array();
    public static function getInstance() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        if (!isset(self::$_instances[$class])) {
            self::$_instances[$class] = new $class();
        }
        return self::$_instances[$class];
    }
}
```

Oh, one more thing: The fact that you are looking for a possibility to re-use code for singleton objects could be a cue to the fact that you are over-using the singleton design pattern! Ask yourself if the classes you are planning to implement as singletons really are singletons and if there will be no use case where you might want to have multiple instances of the particular class.

Often it is much better to use just one singleton representing the current “application context” that provides accessors for objects that are singletons with respect to this context.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly i don't have PHP >= 5.3 on my shared hosting at the moment. But i'll keep this code for the times i will :).

Comment: You forgot to declare $_instances as static as well

Comment: Your explanation of LSB is correct, but then you suggest a workaround for which LSB are implemented in the first place :) His code would work fine with LSB, you just have to redeclare the static instance in the parent classes.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Why I'm looking to do this is because I am creating my own framework that runs a whole range of different applications. By my reasoning, if I even have two singletons, that's just too much copy and paste. I would rather create an abstract class and extend. Then, according to some opinion's I have read, *if* I realise the erroneous horror of my ways in daring to use the singleton pattern, it is easier to change ;)

Answer (score 10):

PHP 5.3+

```
abstract class Singleton
{
    /**
     * Instance
     *
     * @var Singleton
     */
    protected static $_instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Get instance
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    public final static function getInstance() {
        if (null === static::$_instance) {
            static::$_instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: the first instance will be shared among all the derived classes

Answer (score 3):

PHP >= 5.3 only

```
abstract class Base_Factory {
    protected static $factory;
    public static function getInstance(){
        if (!self::$factory) {
            $class = get_called_class();
            self::$factory = new $class();
        }
        return self::$factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 It works. So why would we create a dictionary like in the accepted answer from @FerdinandBeyer ? I think only if we want many singleton instances from the same abstract class, right?

Comment: Update: or in PHP 5.3 for the same reasons as described in the accepted answer. self::$factory will be defined once any derived class is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Register your singletons in a simple class like this

```
class Singletons {
    static private $singleton = array();
    public function getSingleton($class) {
    if (!isset(self::$singleton[$class])) {
        self::$singleton[$class] = new $class;
    }
    return self::$singleton[$class];
    }
}
```

Then do this

```
class aSingleton {
    public $i;
    public function test() {
    ++$this->i;
    echo get_class() . " called {$this->i} times\n";
    }
}

Singletons::getSingleton('aSingleton')->test();
Singletons::getSingleton('aSingleton')->test();
```

Output

```
aSingleton called 1 times
aSingleton called 2 times
```

Comment: May be you will have to have a static member variable that tracks the single instance of aSingleton.

Answer (score -1):

By definition abstract classess cannot be instantiated in PHP like any other object oriented languages. So your Base_Factory should be interface instead of abstract class.

From the PHP manual: "It is not allowed to create an instance of a class that has been defined as abstract."

Comment: Mark seems to know that he cannot instantiate his abstract base class. Hew wants to dynamically instantiate derived, non-abstract classes from code defined in the abstract base class.

Comment: Yes Ferdinand, that's precise.

Answer (score -2):

Well you could do a check to make sure the class calling the function isn't the Base_Factory.

```
if(__CLASS__!='Base_Factory')
```

Then use $this instead of self to refer to the current object instead of the current class.

```
if (!$this->factory)
        $this->factory = new self();
    return $this->factory;
```

Comment: Static functions have no `$this`. Futhermore, `__CLASS__` always represents the class where a function is defined, in your case, it will always be 'Base_Factory', even in derived classes.

Comment: Ah sorry your right, you can't even use get_class($this) as an alternative.